# Linq ToList on empty ItemSource

Tags: c#, linq

This statement will give me null exception, after I clear the datagrid with `this.ProductList.ItemSource = null;:`

```
   salesItem = (from SalesItem items in this.ProductList.ItemsSource
                             select items).ToList<Sales>();
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Check to see if `this.ProductList.ItemsSource` is null or not prior to running the query.   Why are you running a query after it is null?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can solve the problem by not setting ItemsSource to null:

```
this.ProductList.ItemsSource = Enumerable.Empty<Sales>();
```

Comment: this comment should have more upvotes so that people would stop expressing empty collections as `null`, that's so bad and always unexpected

Answer (score 3):

```
if (this.ProductList != null && this.ProductList.ItemsSource != null)
{
    salesItem = (from SalesItem items in this.ProductList.ItemsSource
                             select items).ToList<Sales>();
}
```

Comment: Good catch on the potential nulls.  They're deceptively easy to gloss over in LINQ queries.